# DataGridView gives an error if a table field is binary type

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview

For some reasons, i need to write my own sqlquery tool. it generally works.

[image]

But when i select a table which contains a binary type, it gives me the error i've shown it below.

[image]

I used a DatagridView. My code is below.

```
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string SQL = txtSQL.Text.Trim().ToString();

        try
        {
            gridResult.DataSource = getDataset(SQL).Tables[0];

        }
        catch (SqlException err)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error : " + err.Message + "-" + err.Number);
        }

    }

    public DataSet getDataset(string SQL)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = SQL;
        da.SelectCommand = cmd;
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        conn.Open();
        da.Fill(ds);
        conn.Close();

        return ds;

    }
```

I wonder, Is there any way to prevent showing binary area or prevent giving error? What should do now? Or do you have any idea how can i detect the type of binary field when loading into the gridview programatically?

Comment: Your grid should have `AutoGenerateColumns = true`, if not, it could be your problem.

Comment: What do you mean? It's already true. Any idea?

Comment: I guess your `DataGridView` has some columns added manually.

Comment: No, it's a sqlquey tool and when select a table, tablo must load automatically. So it has to be auto = true